# Packaging error: Email-To-Case

Tags: salesforcedx, email, managed-package, package, email2case

We are facing an issue when trying to create a package version. The test classes seem to be failing due to assert failures. Upon inspection, the underlying issue seems to be:

> **You must enable Email-to-Case Lightning Threading to use this API**

When I deploy the unmanaged code to a scratch org and enable email-to-case the issue is resolved.

Adding the below to the org definition file doesn't seem to be working (the packaging still fails):

```
"caseSettings": {
    "emailToCase" : {
       "enableEmailToCase" : true
    }
}
```

The package includes a functionality to route emails based on certain criterias, here's the code snippet that I suspect is causing the issue:

```
public static String getExistingCaseIdFromThread(Messaging.InboundEmail inboundEmail) {

        // Try to find the Case ID using threading tokens in email attributes.
        Id caseId = EmailMessages.getRecordIdFromEmail(inboundEmail.subject, inboundEmail.plainTextBody, inboundEmail.htmlBody);

        // If we haven't found the Case ID, try finding it using headers.
        if (caseId == null && inboundEmail.headers != null) {
            caseId = Cases.getCaseIdFromEmailHeaders(inboundEmail.headers);
        }
}
```

Packaging this wasn't an issue in December 2023 but is failing now.

**SF CLI Version: 2.23.20**

**EDIT 25 Jan 2024:**
Commenting the below code results in a successful package version:

```
  Id caseId = EmailMessages.getRecordIdFromEmail(inboundEmail.subject, inboundEmail.plainTextBody, inboundEmail.htmlBody);
```

Please let me know if something is unclear. Thanks!

Comment: May I ask, why don't you want to do the org update to activate "Lightning Threading"? Apparantly it's "Test Run Supported" - could you not build a beta package afterwards, verify it can still be installed on all sorts of client orgs (if this is a concern) - and you could still revert everything?!

Comment: We are trying to activate the "Lightning Threading" in the packaging org. Will get back to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This setting in the org definition file seems to have fixed the issue:

```
       "caseSettings": {
            "emailToCase" : {
                "enableEmailToCase" : true,
                "enableOnDemandEmailToCase" : true,
                "enableThreadIDInBody" : true,
                "enableThreadIDInSubject" : true
            }
        }
```

Along with: `sf package version create -f`

**The config file path `(-f)` must be mentioned when creating the package version**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the error means that Email-to-case isn't enabled, but the [Lightning Threading](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389648&type=1) is not enabled.  Per the linked article, it can be enabled via Release Update, which I'm not sure how you specify in a scratch org.  It also mentions:

> Spring ‘24: Salesforce enables a new header-based threading preference, giving customers the flexibility to choose how emails are threaded.

I couldn't find a setting for this in the Metadata API docs, but I could have missed it.  It might be worth trying this:

- spin up a scratch, pull all Settings metadata, commit
- Enable email to case and lightning threading
- pull Settings again and see what's changed.

If you find something in a Settings MD file you'll probably need to move it into the scratch org def.

Comment: The only thing that is relevant that gets added to the settings is 'Email-To-Case' @jasonclark

Comment: Well that's disappointing.  When you created the scratch org, was it W'24 or Sp'24?  I wonder if the Sp'24 changes would have an impact.  You can specify the "preview" release in your scratch def file; see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_target_release_version.htm

Comment: The org is on Winter '24 Patch 17.19. Will test the SP '24 and get back to you.

Comment: Tested with SP'24, Email-To-Case was already enabled and so were some other thread-related settings.`enableThreadTokenInBody` & `enableThreadTokenInSubject`. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: And if you try to build and run tests with the preview release specified, does it still fail?

Comment: Nope, the test runs just fine. We have reached out to Salesforce.

Comment: Sorry, I meant when you try to build the package version with test enabled - I was hoping Sp'24 solved your issue.  Sounds like it doesn't, hence the support case? Please post your resolution if you get one; I'm curious what it is.